# DemandTools Encrypts Field in Conditions

Tags: duplicate-management

I'm trying to create conditions for a single table deduping scenario and I noticed I'm not able to add an encrypted field to my conditions even though I'm able to add the same encrypted field to my list of fields to show. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

I created a short video showing the fields to show, which is working fine and then the conditions which doesn't have my encrypted field. Any thoughts?

http://take.ms/VVQQd

Comment: Do you have "View Encrypted Data" on in your profile